# Solving Bessel's differential equation using Frobenius Method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, differential

So i was told to find the general solution $$2x^2y''-xy'+(x-5)y=0$$ (1) using power series.
After a little manipulation (1) becomes $$y''-\frac{1}{2x}y'+\frac{(x-5)}{2x^2}y=0$$  $$P(x)=\frac{-1}{2x}$$ $$Q(x)=\frac{x-5}{2x^2}$$  $$p(x)=xP(x)=\frac{-1}{2}$$  $$q(x)=x^2Q(x)=\frac{x-5}{2}$$  $$p(0)=\frac{-1}{2}$$ $$q(0)=\frac{-5}{2}$$
thus the indicial equation is $$r(r-1)-\frac{1}{2}r-\frac{5}{2}=0$$ and therefore $$2r^2-3r-5=0$$  $$r_1=-1$$ and $$r_2=\frac{5}{2}$$.
So for $$r=-1$$ $$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n-1}$$   $$y'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$$
and $$y''=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-1)(n-2)a_nx^{n-3}$$
And now the differential equation $$2x^2y''-xy'+(x-5)y=0$$ becomes
$$2x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-1)(n-2)a_nx^{n-3}-x\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n-1}-5\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n-1}=0$$

thus
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty2(n-1)(n-2)a_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-1)a_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty 5a_nx^{n-1}=0$$

For the term $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$ i replaced $n$ with $n-1$ in order for the powers of x to match and therefore we now have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$$  Substituting back to the equation i end up with $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty2(n-1)(n-2)a_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-1)a_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty 5a_nx^{n-1}=0$$

For $n=0$ -> $$5a_0x^{-1}-5a_0x^{-1}=0$$ so $n$ has to be 1 and over.
Therefore $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty [2(n-1)(n-2)a_n-(n-1)a_n+a_{n-1}-5a_n]x^{n-1}=0$$
thus $$a_n=\frac{-a_{n-1}}{n(2n-7)}$$
Here's where i am stuck and i really need your help.. i try to find the pattern by substituting $n=1$ ,$n=2$ etc and for $n=1$ i get $a_1=\frac{a_0}{5}$
for $n=2$ i get $a_2=\frac{1a_0}{5!}$ and for $n=3$ i get $a_3=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1a_0}{5!}$
Am i doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for any idea or possible solution!

Comment: If you put an equation between a pair of double dollar signs (instead of a single pair), you get a displayed one (instead of an inline one). In that way, it is much easier to read your question.

Comment: Thats what i am doing. For example $2x^2+y$ = (dollar sign) 2x^2+y (dollar sign)

Comment: I mean (dollar sign)(dollar sign) equation (dollar sign)(dollar sign), without a space between two consecutive dollar signs. That is why I said a pair of *double* dollar signs.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Put the . and the , inside the dollar signs and not after them.

Comment: The pattern in the coefficient structure will only properly emerge when $(2n-7)>0$, that is, for $n\ge 4$. All what comes before is some coefficient that you can read arbitrary structure into. The changing part in the denominator should be something like $(2n-6)!(n-2)(n-1)n$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If we solve for $2n-7>0$ we get $n=\frac{7}{2}$ . I am sorry but i dont understand why we  have to do that. I know that the denomenator has to be > 0 but $n=\frac{7}{2}$ is equal to $3.5$ . I tried to substitute $r=\frac{5}{2}$ but the pattern is way more complicated .